# Error from p5.sound in browser when it is hosted via HTTP?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, networking, microsoft-edge, p5.js

I use p5.js in my school project and it does not work in Google Chrome(also Microsoft Edge, idk about Opera), with JavaScript activated, but only when its on hosting. When I got it on Localhost it works just fine. In Mozilla it works in both situations. Iam confused.

http://klauzury2c2021.8u.cz/
you can find all of the code on the site

[image: error screenshot]

[image: head of html code]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are are hitting [this issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/454) with the p5.Sound library that prevents it from working correctly when loaded over http. Since you're hosting your site on a public server the best solution would be to enable HTTPS for your server and have HTTP requests redirect to the HTTPS url. However if you are unable to do this you can make this work with an AudioWorklet polyfill. Just add the following line to the head of your html file:

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@free-side/audioworklet-polyfill/dist/audioworklet-polyfill.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

#### Updated ↑ Old Answer ↓

I originally misread your question and though you were specifically struggling with testing on localhost. Here are instructions for cases where you are testing with a **local** server:

Apparently people have had success working around the issue using a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Which allows you to expose a local service via a public HTTPS endpoint. So if you're running a local HTTP server on port `3000` you would open a terminal and run `ngrok http 3000` (having followed the basic installation and setup steps for ngrok). Nrok will assign you a public URL, which it will display in a message to the terminal like this:

```
Forwarding                    https://<UNIQUE_ID_HERE>.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:3000
```

Then instead of accessing your sketch page via `http://localhost:3000/` you can access it via `https://<UNIQUE_ID_HERE>.ngrok.io/` and that should work around this p5.sound issue.

Comment: I tried the ngrok first and it worked great, so I tried to move it to HTTPS and it worked, you can also try it https://jankozeluh.g6.cz/index.html

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it working. Very cool sketch, I wound up fiddling with it for a while while testing. I was inspired to make this less advanced sketch: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1195534 with adaptations of some of your graphing code.